# How can I post a welcome message to a newly joined user via a Slack bot?

Tags: node.js, slack-api

I am trying to leverage Slack's Real-time messaging (RTM) API to post a welcome message to newly joined users of my team from a "Greeter Bot".

The event I'm listening for is [`team_join`](https://api.slack.com/events/team_join).

I have confirmed that the event is firing, and that messages can be sent to previously joined users out upon receiving that event. However, when trying to notify the *newly joined user*, nothing comes through.
I've played around with adding a delay (up to 45secs) after receiving the event before notifying the user, but still no dice.

Here my `index.js` file:

```js
var SlackBot = require('slackbots');

var bot = new SlackBot({
  token: process.env.SLACK_TOKEN || '',
  name: process.env.BOT_NAME || 'greeterbot'
});

bot.on('message', function(data) {
  var self = this;
  if ('team_join' === data.type) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var message = 'hello.';
      // this works. 'some crusty old user' gets a DM message from my greeterbot.
      self.postMessageToUser('some crusty old user', message, { as_user: true });
      // FAIL. what am i doing wrong?!
      self.postMessageToUser(data.user.name, message, { as_user: true });
    }, 45000);
    console.log("'" + data.user.name + "' has joined the team."); // works. the user name is present in the log.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. There is a caching issue with the underlying bot library that I'm using.

For reference, here is a link to a PR that aims to address this issue.
https://github.com/mishk0/slack-bot-api/pull/25

Switching libs now.

Answer (score 1):

Our Slack team, [SKGTech.io](http://skgtech.io) uses [Janitr](https://janitr.net) that we wrote. Janitr is a Slack bot that welcomes new users based on your preferences.